# How to prove $\Theta(g(n))\cup o(g(n))\ne O(g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

How to prove $\Theta(g(n))\cup o(g(n))\ne O(g(n))$ ?

Is there a simple example for understanding? Seems there's a gap between $O(g(n))- \Theta(g(n))$ and $o(g(n))$ just from the definition. But I cannot understand What kind of function lays there?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: Unfold the respective definitions and look for gaps. In particular, note the different kind of definition of $o$ compared to $O$! The [usual tools for comparing functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/827/98) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} g(n) & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\ g(n)/n & \text{if $n$ is odd}. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\Theta$ means "always roughly as big as". Little-o means "getting smaller and smaller compared to". Big-O means "always at most as big as" (all up to some constant).

Functions that are in O (g(n)) but neither in $\Theta (g(n))$ nor in o(g(n)) are those that vary between being as large as g(n) up to a constant and being arbitrary small compared to g(n). That's what Yuval's example does; it is often as large as g(n) but sometimes arbitrarily small compared to g(n). Both infinitely many times.